# How to easily convert Joda YearMonth to LocalDateTime

Tags: java, jodatime

As per the question title, I was wondering if there was something a little less verbose than this:

```
new YearMonth(2014, 1).toLocalDate(1).toLocalDateTime(new LocalTime())
```

maybe a utility method or instance method?

Comment: Why do you not like that? YearMonth is just a partial date, so the day of month is required to create a full local date out of it. Still a local date is not a local date time, because the time is missing. So another method call is required. All in all long, but self-explanatory.

Comment: I guess it is. The alternative would be something like: new YearMonth(2014, 1).toLocalDateTime() with default day and time but it's arguable if that's good practice or not.

Comment: OK, I thought 2014 and 1 are just for example and not constants! If year, month and day are fixed, you can also try: new LocalDateTime(new LocalDate(2014, 1, 1))

Comment: 2014 and 1 are just for example.

Answer (score 2):

Your example uses the current time. If that was arbitrary, and midnight will do, try:

```
new LocalDateTime(1980, 1, 1, 0, 0).withFields(new YearMonth(2014, 1))
```

You can then pull the LocalDateTime into a constant for more brevity:

```
FIRST_OF_MONTH.withFields(new LocalDateTime(2014, 1))
```

Or, equivalently to your proposed "toLocalDateTime":

```
LocalDateTime.now().withFields(new LocalDateTime(2014, 1))
```